# Question in the "input" type range, and JavaScript to design the video player

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to control in the period and change its color while updating the movement of the cursor specified in the [picture](https://i.suar.me/EnqQx/)

What is the name of that period in the CSS and how will the code in Java Script be in that case?

```js
var video = document.querySelector('.video');
var btn = document.getElementById('play-pause');

function intializePlayer() {
  btn = document.getElementById("play-pause");
  seekslider = document.getElementById("seekslider");
  // Add event listeners
  seekslider.addEventListener("change", vidSeek, false);
  video.addEventListener("timeupdate", seektimeupdate, false);
}

window.onload = intializePlayer;

function vidSeek() {
  var seekto = video.duration * (seekslider.value / 100);
  video.currentTime = seekto;
}

function seektimeupdate() {
  var nt = video.currentTime * (100 / video.duration);
  seekslider.value = nt;
  if (video.ended) {
    btn.className = "play";
  }
}
```

```css
#seekslider {
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #000;
  border: #666 1px solid;
  height: 4px;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
```

Comment: Hello Ka1TTx and welcome to Stack Overflow. The easiest way to find any info on an element in an HTML is to right-click it and choose "Inspect element". This will bring up the Developer Tools of your browser and highlight the clicked element, along with the complete source code showing ID and classes that might have been set.

Comment: I know and have tried it but it did not work because it is what I think about the browser and each browser has a code element of the same function , and now I was able to find what I need in the browsers" edge, IE and firefox " but the remaining now are chrome and opera and all I need is to know Control code for progress only
And anyway I thank you for answering ♥

Comment: If you want to color only the part that is elapsed, this will only work natively in Internet Explorer via `::-ms-fill-lower` and `::-ms-fill-upper` pseudo classes. Others don't natively support it so you would need to track the pointer position via JS and i.e. use an overlay over the slider bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments only Internet Explorer allows you to natively design the elapsed and remaining parts of the slider, at least that's what I got from this [well-written post about styling range sliders](http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html).

There are alternatives, though, that you might use. One idea I tried is to put the range slider into a `DIV` that holds elements to display the progress. The background element would be (kind of) the width of the slider while the foreground element (the "progress indicator") would expand according to the value of the slider. Please note that I did not change the appearance of the slider itself but if you want to do so, read the above article, it's worth the time.

---

Let's move on to the relevant code.

**HTML code**

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper" style="width: 500px;">
  <div class="slider-underlay"></div>
  <input class="seekslider" type="range" min="30" max="60" value="0" step="1">
  <div class="slider-progress"></div>
</div>
```

The slider sits in the middle of the background element that defines the background color and the foreground element that will indicate the progress.

**CSS code**

```
.slider-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 310px;
}
.slider-underlay {
  background-color: black;  
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slider-progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #999;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.seekslider {
  width: 98%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
}
```

**JS code**

```
$(".seekslider").on('change, input', function() {
  const ratio = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min);
  const counterRatio = (0.5 - ratio) * 1.2;
  const counterWidth = counterRatio * 10 + 2;
  const width= $(this).width();
  $(this).next('.slider-progress').width(ratio * width + counterWidth);
});
```

Due to internal padding inside the slider element itself (the thumb slider will only be touching the left or right side of the countrol's outer width) we need to apply a bit of adjustment. When the slider is on the left, we need to make the progress indicator's width to be a little wider but as soon as we progress to the right, we need to reduce the extra padding, otherwise the progress would be exceeded the thumb slider on the right. The values above have been configured through experimenting and might need adjustment and there is a good chance that there are way better implementations available on the Net.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/EBwZrE).

Aside from the wrapper all elements scale in percents so you may play around with the width of the slider.

Here are some demo images taken from the Codepen:

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

**Edge**

[image: Edge]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

Please let me know about what you think and if this might be a solution for you. Thanks.